# mysql select from 2 other columns in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this but much longer...

```
| CategoryID | Category | ParentCategoryID |
+------------+----------+------------------+
| 23         | Screws   | 3                |
| 3          | Packs    | 0                |
```

I am aiming to retrieve one column from this which in this instance would give me the following...

```
| Category     |
+--------------+
| Packs/Screws |
```

Please excuse me for not knowing exactly how to word this, so far I can only think to split the whole table into multiple tables and use LEFT JOIN, this seems like a very good opportunity for a learning curve however.

I realise that CONCAT() will come into play when combining the two retrieved Category names but beyond that I am stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(x.category,'/',y.category) Category
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.categoryid = x.parentcategoryid
[WHERE x.parentcategoryid = 0]
```